# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6

I use `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` without problem, except in iOS 8.

Steps to reproduce:

- Launch application in portrait, the recognizer works fine, with edge in 20 pixel from edge.
- Rotate to landscape, the recognizer can activate at 50 (or more) pixels from edge.

This behavior don't happen when i launch in iOS 7, only with iOS 8. It look like the detection frame expand in size, like autoresize function.

It's something in my code or you can reproduce this bug yourself ?

Edit: As Donkey said, it's only on simulator now, that's a lot better ! ;)